# Pedometer with strong privacy (no data in cloud, local analysis software, no iOS)

Tags: privacy, cloud-computing

I wish to do 10,000 steps a day. Now searching for an accurate pedometer. I don't wish a cloud solution, data must be local and a nice analysis software.

What do you recommend me? I am using a Mac.

Comment: In ye olden days these gadgets were entirely mechanical.

Comment: And no, this is not a [question fit for StackExchange](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

anything you will use with your cell phone attached, will have a data connection to the "cloud" and you will be at the mercy of the application developers, if your data was being collected or not, even if they might claim "anonymously". So, your best bet is to buy a decent pedometer from a pharmacy, online or off, carry on you all day and manually enter the step count, at the end of the day to the analysis program of your choice.